# Can't switch Eval from Entity Framework to ADO.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to apply `Eval` to a simple table (in ASP.NET)

It works with Entity Framework, but I want to try it with basic ADO.NET, the information table is not available (I just get a black white screen, and no error message)

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Urunler">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table style="width: 500px;">
                <tr>
                    <td><%#Eval("FirstName") %></td>
                    <td><%#Eval("LastName") %></td>
                    <td><%#Eval("Country") %></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

This is the code behind:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                cnn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FirstName,LastName,Country FROM Employees", cnn);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                      while (dr.Read())
                      {
                         Urunler.DataSource = dr.GetString(0);
                         Urunler.DataSource = dr.GetString(1);
                      }
                }
                cnn.Close();

                //this was the EntityFW code which worked;
                //Urunler.DataSource = db.Employees.Select(emp => new
                //{
                //    emp.FirstName,
                //    emp.LastName,
                //    emp.Country
                //}).ToList();
                //Urunler.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to switch to basic ADO.Net?

Comment: @GertArnold I want to see how it works in basic ADO.Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EF code creates a list of anonymous objects. The basic ADO.Net code creates nothing, it just repeatedly sets a `DataSource` by a string (which is impossible).

You have to make your ADO.Net code create a list of objects too:

```
var data = new List<EmployeeDto>();
...
while (dr.Read())
{
     data.Add(new EmployeeDto { 
                                FirstName = dr.GetString(0),
                                LastName = dr.GetString(1),
                                Country = dr.GetString(2)
                              });
}
...
Urunler.DataSource = data;
Urunler.DataBind();
```

where `EmployeeDto` is a simple class having the three listed properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
dr.Read();                      
Urunler.DataSource = dr;
Urunler.DataBind();
//while (dr.Read())
//{
//    Urunler.DataSource = dr.GetString(0);
//    Urunler.DataSource = dr.GetString(1);
//}
```